# Подсчёт количество записей в бд с PDO

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Как быстрее и правильнее подсчитать количество записей в базе данных mysql, используя PDO?
так

```
$query=$dbh->query("SELECT id FROM users");
$members=$query->rowCount();
```

или так

```
$query=$dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users");
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$row=$query->fetch();
$members=$row['count'];
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логически второй. В первом случае из бд выгружаются все строки (особенно весело, если их 1000+), второй же... Создан для подсчёта количества записей :)

Comment: Внешность обманчива...=) четыре строчки выполнятся быстрее двух)

Comment: но с where это уже будет не правильно?

Answer (score 3):

Разумеется, только второй вариант. Тем более, что его можно записать гораздо проще:

```
$members=$dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM users")->fetchColumn();
```